# How does Keras handles (?,?) input shapes? Able to train Keras VGG16 on Cifar10 despite input_shape smaller than minimum

Tags: keras

I am extremely confused that Keras allowed me to train my model: I was able to load the pretrained vgg16 model, hooked it up with a GlobalAvgPool and Dense layers that ultimately output 10 classes for CIFAR10. Then was able to train it (with decent accuracy).

However, when I explicitly specify the input_shape in VGG16(), the ValueError appeared and I realize that my input images (batch, 32,32,3) should not be able to go through the network, as there are 5 MaxPool layers with 2x2 filters and stride 2!

```python
ValueError: Input size must be at least 48x48; got `input_shape=(32, 32, 3)`
```

So, how does Keras handle the former case and still allow training to proceed?

My code:

```python
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

batch_size = 32
num_classes = 10
epochs = 10

# Convert class vectors to binary class matrices.
y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)


x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255

from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.optimizers import Adam #rmsprop
from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint


def ourModel():
  '''
  returns a model up to the the Model(inputs=,outputs=) and freeze-layers step.
  Optimizer and compiler to be defined separately.
  '''
  # create the base pre-trained model
  base_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

  # add a global spatial average pooling layer
  x = base_model.output
  x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
  # let's add a fully-connected layer
  x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
  # and a logistic layer -- let's say we have 'num_classes' of classes
  predictions = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

  # this is the model we will train
  model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

  # first: train only the top layers (which were randomly initialized)
  # i.e. freeze all convolutional layers
  for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

  return model
```